# Сравнение JTextField со String выдаёт значение лож хотя должно правду

Tags: java

Помогите решить проблему.
Я JTextField сравниваю со значением String но значения почему то не равно.
пример в поле ввода JTextField  стоит x ,а в if(JTextField  == "x")выдаёт что эти значения не равны можете сказать по чему и как это решить.
https://dropmefiles.com/P2mM2 
Ошибка в

```
protected static void lef(String battones) {
        createMacro();
        String x = battones;
        if(x == "x") {//тут не равно хотя дебаг говорит что x = "x"
            macro.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);//нажать
            macro.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);//отпустить
        }
        if(x == "y"){
            macro.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);//нажать
            macro.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Y);//отпустить
        }
    }
```

Comment: там описывается как сравнивать а у меня при сравнении x == x выдаётся  лож

Comment: сравнивайте `String` через .equals()
`x.equals("x")`

Comment: хм получилось а в чём разница между .equals и ==

Comment: @bkmz по предложенной ссылке это подробно описано.